# Best subset of matrix with minimum number of co-occuring non NA values?

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, graph-algorithm, subgraph

I have a N by T matrix of data (N >>T), which have many missing NA values. I am searching for the best row-subset of my matrix, such that any two rows N_i and N_j will have at least k>=2 co-occurring (i.e. occurring at same time t) non-NA values. To motivate this, my end goal of finding this subset is to be able to compute a pairwise correlation matrix (using R's `cor(., use="pairwise.complete.obs")` as initial estimator for a shrinkage procedure.

Formally, if X is my raw matrix, let Y be the matrix where each entry has value 1 if corresponding X entry has an observed value, 0 for NA. Then YY' will be a N x N matrix counting co-occurrences of non-NA values. Initially this YY' matrix will contain 0 values, indicating that row N_i and N_j have 0 co-occurring values. I want to find the largest subset of X such that the minimum of YY' is say k=2 , or 3, etc.

Is there any algorithm to solve this question, with ideally an implementation in R? I have a feeling this YY' matrix can be considered like a graph, and that there might exist known procedures for this question (clique finding? Steiner tree?) but I am not knowledgeable enough in this domain... I can think of a greedy iterative algorithm removing the worst row each time and re-computing YY, but was hoping there would be a more elegant and faster solution?

Quick simulation of the data:

```r
set.seed(123)
X <- matrix(rnorm(200*20), 200, 20)
X[sample(1:(200*20), 200*20/2)] <- NA
Y <- 1*!is.na(X)
YY <- tcrossprod(Y)
YY[1:3,1:3]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    9    6    3
#> [2,]    6   10    4
#> [3,]    3    4   11
min(YY)
#> [1] 0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Reading over your post, is this a typo: " I want to find the smallest subset of X such that the minimum of YY' is say k=2 , or 3, etc." I assume you meant, "I want to find the **largest** subset of X such that the minimum of YY' is say k=2, or 3, etc."

Comment: A very simple greedy iterative algorithm: at each iteration, scan the rows of YY' for a row with the most entries below `k`. Remove this entry from X, recompute YY' and repeat. Terminate when no row in YY' has entries below `k`.

Comment: thanks for the typo, my bad! And yes, I had thought of that greedy procedure, but was hoping there would be a more elegant solution! Just edited the text accordingly. Thanks @ldog

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this problem is NP-hard. Given a graph with n vertices and m edges, we can reduce the problem of finding a max clique to solving this problem with k=1 on the vertex-edge incidence matrix (duplicate columns for higher k).

I'd turn the reduction around in the obvious way and reduce this problem to max clique.

The vertices of the graph correspond to rows. There is an edge between two vertices iff the corresponding rows have enough non-NA coöccurring values. To find the max clique, you can call out to the [igraph R package](https://igraph.org/r/doc/cliques.html).

Comment: thanks for your answer! Would you mind giving some basic background on this, targeting a beginner audience? What are the vertices and edges in my case, the N observations and the non-0 entries of YY'? What's the standard name for my problem at hand? The type of data I have has at most N=7000 and T=20, but I don't think T's dimension plays much of  a role, if we are focusing on the YY' matrix of dim N x N? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Matifou added some description of how to solve using max clique.

Comment: @Matifou As for the standard problem name, I don't want to speak authoritatively without consulting the literature, but because of the close correspondence with max clique, I'm not sure that it would have its own name (instead of being studied as max clique on a restricted class of graphs).

Comment: thanks! I understand better, but still confused about your middle sentence "turn the reduction around in the obvious way"? Note that igraph uses only undirected graphs, so I converted my YY' to a 1/0 matrix, with 1 if YY' entry has value>=1. How should I do for higher k? Iteratively, or simply setting the undirected YY' for value>= k? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Matifou yes, threshold YY'.